# Secret not working with @googlemaps/google-maps-services-js and firebase function

Tags: javascript, firebase, environment-variables, google-maps-api-2, secret-key

I am developing a mobile app with React Native.
I create a serverless function which I deploy on Firebase to find a place nearby with Google Maps API.
I can get the data if I insert manually the Google Key in the code but if I use either google secret manager or env variable doesn't work.
I console log the key both using env and google secret manager and I can see the value.
But seems that is not available to the code when it does the request to the API.
I use  `@googlemaps/google-maps-services-js` module to do such request.

This is my function:

```
// index.js
const { onRequest } = require("firebase-functions/v2/https");
const { placesRequest } = require("./places");
const { Client } = require("@googlemaps/google-maps-services-js");
const client = new Client({});

exports.placesRequest = onRequest((request, response) => {
  placesRequest(request, response, client);
});
```

```
// places.js
const { defineSecret } = require("firebase-functions/params");
const googleApiKey = defineSecret("GOOGLE_API_KEY");
const { mocks, addMockImages } = require("./mock");
const url = require("url");
const functions = require("firebase-functions");

module.exports.placesRequest = (req, res, client) => {
  const { location, mock } = url.parse(req.url, true).query;

  if (mock === "true") {
    const data = mocks[location];
    if (data) {
      data.results = data.results.map(addMockImages);
    }
    res.json(data);
  }

 functions.logger.log("Logging googleApiKey from secret:", googleApiKey);
  functions.logger.log(
    "Logging googleApiKey from env:",
    process.env.GOOGLE_API_KEY
  );

  client
    .placesNearby({
      params: {
        location,
        radius: 1500, //15km - is set in meter
        key: process.env.GOOGLE_API_KEY, // or googleApiKey
      },
      timeout: 1000,
    })
    .then((response) => {
      console.log("place response", response.data);
      response.data.results = response.data.results.map(addGoogleImage);
      return res.json(response.data);
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      res.status(400);
      return res.send(err);
    });
};
```

Any tips? Would be highly appreciate

Answer (score 0):

I manage to fix it.
I simply created another variable in the env file and give different name and same value.
No idea what was the problem... maybe the name I gave is already taken from Google space, or maybe there was some invisible space or chars.
Another lessons how starting from scratch when I am stuck is a good idea ;)

Google Secret manager still doesn't work, but I did not put the work to discover why.